# cc1: error: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror]

Tags: c++11, gcc, nginx

I need the `-std=c++11` flag for c++ modules when compile nginx. If I configure nginx with `--with-cc-opt="-std=c++11"` and then `make`. It gives me the error described in the title. How can I get it compile without modifing nginx source code or the compiler(for now it's gcc 4.8) version?

Comment: Nginx sources are C and the build system compiles with a C compiler. The `-std=c++11` is a flag for the C++ compiler.

Comment: @BorkoJandras That flag is for modules written in c++.

Comment: Configure script help says: `--with-cc-opt=OPTIONS  set additional C compiler options`. That would mean that this flag will be used on C sources as well

Comment: @BorkoJandras The quest is not about `--with-cc-opt`, It's about setting the `-std=c++11` flag for nginx modules written in c++.

Comment: While technically correct — the core nginx files seem to be C only — many modules and add-ons are actually written in C++. Notably, Google's BoringSSL module not only requires C++, it demands _at least_ C++14 (!), and I presume that this question needs to deal with such dependencies. Actually, I'm also wondering how to do this :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: "--with-cc-opt=parameters — sets additional parameters that will be added to the CFLAGS variable."

CFLAGS enables the addition of switches for the C compiler, while CXXFLAGS is meant to be used when invoking a C++ compiler.

Comment: 100% correct, but not really useful for the OP, who probably needs to use C++ to compile some modules/dependencies of nginx, even though the nginx core doesn't appear to use C++.